# Django - What is the reason for "can't set attribute" error in this form?

Tags: django, django-forms

In my Django project, I'm receiving the "can't set attribute" error on runtime, when loading a CreateView which looks like this:

```
class DonationCreateView(InventoryEditingPermissionMixin, CreateView):
    model = Donation
    template_name = 'inventories/donation/donation_form.html'
    form_class = DonationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('donations_list')
    success_message = 'Donación creada correctamente'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save()
        amount = obj.amount
        autotank = obj.auto_tank
        tank = SaleWarehouseTank.objects.filter(
            warehouse__id=autotank.pk).last()
        tank.current_level -= amount
        tank.save(update_fields=['current_level'])
        self.object = obj
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DonationCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['autotanks'] = SaleWarehouse.objects.filter(type=0)
        context['user_type'] = self.request.user.user_type
        context['clients'] = Client.objects.all()
        context['initial_client_name'] = ''
        context['is_update'] = False
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super(DonationCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return form_kwargs
```

And "DonationForm" looks like this:

```
class DonationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    client_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Cliente')
    region = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Region.objects.all(), required=False, label='Región')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.user_type = user.user_type
        super(DonationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['auto_tank'].required = False
        self.fields['client'].required = False
        self.fields['client'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        if user.user_type == 'region_admin':
            self.fields['auto_tank'].queryset = SaleWarehouse.objects.filter(type=0, region__id=user.region_id)
        elif user.user_type == 'admin':
            self.fields['auto_tank'].queryset = SaleWarehouse.objects.filter(type=0)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        client_name = cleaned_data['client_name']
        if client_name.strip() == '':
            cleaned_data['client'] = None
        else:
            if Client.objects.filter(social_reason__icontains=client_name).count() > 0:
                cleaned_data['client'] = Client.objects.filter(social_reason__icontains=client_name).last()
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Por favor, elige un cliente de la lista, o deja el espacio en blanco')
        region = cleaned_data['region']
        auto_tank = cleaned_data['auto_tank']
        if self.user_type == 'admin':
            if str(region) in ['', 'None']:
                self._errors['region'] = self.error_class(['Por favor, selecciona una región.'])
            else:
                if str(auto_tank) in ['', 'None']:
                    self._errors['auto_tank'] = self.error_class(['Por favor, selecciona un autotanque.'])
        elif self.user_type == 'region_admin':
            if str(auto_tank) in ['', 'None']:
                self._errors['auto_tank'] = self.error_class(['Por favor, selecciona un autotanque'])
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Donation
        fields = ('region', 'auto_tank', 'client', 'client_name', 'amount', 'admin_confirm', 'observations')
```

Why could this error be triggering on runtime, when I load the CreateView? What other information should I look into to find out the cause of the error?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem, and it was neither on the Form nor the View, but on my model. My model looked like this:

```
class Donation(Expense):
   client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Cliente')
   date_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha y hora', auto_now_add=True)
   auto_tank = models.ForeignKey(SaleWarehouse,
```

on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='Autotanque')
admin_confirm = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Gasto autorizado", default=False, blank=True)

And the model "Expense" from which it inherited, had this:

```
class Expense(models.Model):
   amount = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Cantidad', null=False, blank=False, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(300000.0)])
   time = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Hora', auto_now_add=True)
   date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Tiempo', auto_now_add=True)
   observations = models.CharField(verbose_name='Observaciones', null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)

   @property
   def date_time(self):
       return datetime.datetime.combine(date=self.date, time=self.time)
```

The field "date_time" in Donation was clashing with the property "date_time" in Expense. Removing the property from the Expense class fixed the issue.